# Error on bar 5361: Invalid format the str.format_time() function: Asia/Kolkata

Tags: format

Error on bar 5361: Invalid format

the str.format_time() function:

Asia/Kolkata.

Error on bar 5361: Invalid format

the str.format_time() function:

Asia/Kolkata.
I did change time format also but not working
please help. its very good script